# How to correctly set Query Layout to grid?

Tags: html, grid, orchardcms

In Orchard, I've created a Query that filters on a "Student" content type, and i'm trying to list my Students in a grid. So I added a new layout to the Query and set the following properties :

- Layout Type: Grid
- Display Mode: Properties (and I added the required
  properties from the Content Type)
- Display Type: Detail (I am not sure if this is correct)
- Grouping: None
- Alignment: Horizontal
- Number of Columns: Was automatically set to 3

HTML Properties:

- GridTag: table
- Row Tag: tr
- Cell Tag: td

But this didn't display the grid correctly. The rows populated horizontally instead of vertically. Please check the screenshot below:

[image]

What I need is the normal grid layout, where I have the column names in the first row and then each row represents the data for a single content Item.

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I'm using Orchard as a Web Project. All my customization is done through the Admin Panel, so I can't adjust the code. My question is if I can do that with out-of-the-box properties of Orchard.

Edit#2:

When setting the alignment to vertical, here's the resulting display:
[image]

Comment: can you make fiddle ? or provide some code

Comment: Well, I'm using Orchard as a Web Project, I can't customize the code.

Comment: can you please give Orchard  documentation link ?

Comment: Here is the Documentation: http://docs.orchardproject.net/

Comment: I think you just need Alignment: vertical, which will stack the results instead of having a column for each result

Comment: @devqon Thank you for your suggestion. Please check the edited question, I added a screenshot for the Alignment Vertical. It still doesn't achieve the required result

Answer (score 1):

If you choose Alignment: horizontal, Orchard will render the items just like you described; next to each other.

If you just choose Alignment: vertical, Orchard will render the items stacked, where the columns are the properties of the item.

When you look at the code of Orchard.Projections/Providers/Layouts/GridLayout.cs, you can see the following code:

```
public dynamic RenderLayout(LayoutContext context, IEnumerable<LayoutComponentResult> layoutComponentResults) {

    bool horizontal = Convert.ToString(context.State.Alignment) != "vertical"; 

    //..

    return Shape.Grid(Id: gridId, Horizontal: horizontal, Columns: columns, Items: shapes, Tag: gridTag, Classes: new[] { gridClass }, RowTag: rowTag, RowClasses: new[] { rowClass }, CellTag: cellTag, CellClasses: new[] { cellClass }, EmptyCell: emptyCell);
}
```

This means that Orchard will render a shape called 'Grid', with the Horizontal property set to `Alignment != "vertical"`.

To see how this grid shape is actually rendered, you can go to Orchard.Projections/Providers/Layouts/LayoutShapes.cs, and see this code:

```
[Shape]
public void Grid(dynamic Display, TextWriter Output, HtmlHelper Html, string Id, bool Horizontal, IEnumerable<dynamic> Items, int Columns, string Tag, IEnumerable<string> Classes, IDictionary<string, string> Attributes, string RowTag, IEnumerable<string> RowClasses, IDictionary<string, string> RowAttributes, string CellTag, IEnumerable<string> CellClasses, IDictionary<string, string> CellAttributes, string EmptyCell) {
    //..

    // Here Orchard decides the columns and rows:
    if (!Horizontal) {
        seekItem = (row, col) => col*Columns + row;
        maxCols = maxRows;
        maxRows = Columns;
    }

    //..
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use this to configure my grid properly

Comment: To gain the most control, you can just use the Layout option 'Shape'. Then create the shape that you named and have full control over how to render the items

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```html
<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name <a href="#">Jeff McDonald</a>
      </td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Spain</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name <a href="#">John Alex</a>
      </td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name <a href="#">Kim Lincoln</a>
      </td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>netherland</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes but how can I set Orchard to do that?